# Display error when moving the camera in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, c++-cli

I have a problem in my project, when I move the camera in a location near the image for me is perfect, but as far I move or rotate the camera, it gives me error like this.
 I do not know where my error is. How can I correct this?

http://nr7.upanh.com/b5.s32.d2/b7f577d38c0b23cbb35ca367e253b716_50312137.orr.png
http://nr9.upanh.com/b2.s11.d1/0be16f4300e3a84aba3a56e5e2bf008d_50312139.perfec.png

code:

```
ButtonEndRollVV KeyPessUp;
VeKhungCanh Draw;
GLint ListDraw[100];


void glintIn()
{
    glutWarpPointer(400,300);
    KeyPessUp.lastx=400;
    KeyPessUp.lasty=300;
    KeyPessUp.xrot=ROLL_X;
    KeyPessUp.yrot=ROLL_Y;
    KeyPessUp.xpos=-DEFAUTCAMERAX;
    KeyPessUp.ypos=-DEFAUTCAMERAY;
    KeyPessUp.zpos=-DEFAUTCAMERAZ;
/////////////////////////////////set defual/////////////////////////////////////
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);// Enables Depth Testing
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                         // Depth Buffer Setup                           
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glClearStencil(0);//gia phong bo dem dat no bang 0
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);//kich hoat bo dem stencil
////////////////////////////////create list grid///////////////////////////////
    ListDraw[0]=glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(ListDraw[0],GL_COMPILE);
    {
        Draw.CreateKhongGian();
    }
    glEndList();
/////////////////////////////////create cong hang hai//////////////////////////
    ListDraw[1]=glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(ListDraw[1],GL_COMPILE);
    {
        Draw.CreateCongHangHai();
    }
    glEndList();
/////////////////////////////create hang giao/////////////////////////////////
    ListDraw[2]=glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(ListDraw[2],GL_COMPILE);
    {
        Draw.CreateHangGiao();
    }
    glEndList();
//////////////////////////////////anh sang va thong so vat lieu////////////////////////////

    float Al[4] = {0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, Al ); 

    float Dl[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, Dl ); 

    float Sl[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, Sl );

        float Am[4] = {0.6f,0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, Am );

    float Dm[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, Dm );

    float Sm[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, Sm );

   glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 45);
   glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE);//bo cai nay neu bumapping
   glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glPushMatrix();


    glRotatef(KeyPessUp.xrot,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(KeyPessUp.yrot,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(KeyPessUp.xpos,KeyPessUp.ypos,KeyPessUp.zpos); 
    glCallList(ListDraw[0]);//draw grid
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    glCallList(ListDraw[1]);//draw Cong Hang Hai pt parabol: 
    glCallList(ListDraw[2]);//draw Hang Giao


    glPopMatrix();

    glFinish();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void resize(int w,int h)
{
       glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
       glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
       glLoadIdentity ();
       //SIZE_KHUNG_CANH*2
       float DefaultFus=0.001f;
       glFrustum (-DefaultFus, DefaultFus, -DefaultFus, DefaultFus, DefaultFus,SIZE_KHUNG_CANH*3 );
       glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);        
       glutPostRedisplay();
       KeyPessUp.sizeH=h;
       KeyPessUp.sizeW=h;
}
void idle()
{
    if(KeyPessUp.keyStates[GLUT_KEY_UP]==true)
    {
            float xrotrad, yrotrad;
            yrotrad = (KeyPessUp.yrot / 180 * pi);
            xrotrad = (KeyPessUp.xrot / 180 * pi); 
            KeyPessUp.xpos -= float(sin(yrotrad)/SPEED) ;
            KeyPessUp.zpos += float(cos(yrotrad)/SPEED) ;
            if(DISABLEUPDOWNCAMERA==0)
                KeyPessUp.ypos += float(sin(xrotrad)/SPEED) ;//bỏ đi nếu nhập vai
    }
    if(KeyPessUp.keyStates[GLUT_KEY_LEFT]==true)
    {
            float xrotrad, yrotrad;
            yrotrad = ((KeyPessUp.yrot+90) / 180 * pi);
            xrotrad = ((KeyPessUp.xrot) / 180 * pi); 
            KeyPessUp.xpos += float(sin(yrotrad)/SPEED) ;
            KeyPessUp.zpos -= float(cos(yrotrad)/SPEED) ;
            if(DISABLEUPDOWNCAMERA==0)
                KeyPessUp.ypos -= float(sin(xrotrad)/SPEED) ;//bỏ đi nếu nhập vai
    }
    if(KeyPessUp.keyStates[GLUT_KEY_DOWN]==true)
    {

            float xrotrad, yrotrad;
            yrotrad = (KeyPessUp.yrot / 180 * pi);
            xrotrad = (KeyPessUp.xrot / 180 * pi); 
            KeyPessUp.xpos += float(sin(yrotrad)/SPEED);
            KeyPessUp.zpos -= float(cos(yrotrad)/SPEED) ;
            if(DISABLEUPDOWNCAMERA==0)
                KeyPessUp.ypos -= float(sin(xrotrad)/SPEED);    //bỏ đi nếu nhập vai
    }
    if(KeyPessUp.keyStates[GLUT_KEY_RIGHT]==true)
    {
         float xrotrad, yrotrad;
            yrotrad = ((KeyPessUp.yrot+90) / 180 * pi);
            xrotrad = ((KeyPessUp.xrot) / 180 * pi); 
            KeyPessUp.xpos -= float(sin(yrotrad)/SPEED);
            KeyPessUp.zpos += float(cos(yrotrad)/SPEED) ;
            if(DISABLEUPDOWNCAMERA==0)
                KeyPessUp.ypos += float(sin(xrotrad)/SPEED);//bỏ đi nếu nhập vai
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void KeyPess(int Key,int x,int y)
{
    if(KeyPessUp.acted==0)
    {
        glutIdleFunc(idle);
        KeyPessUp.acted=1;
    }
    KeyPessUp.keyStates[Key]=true;  
}
void KeyUp(int Key,int x,int y)
{
    int check=0;
    KeyPessUp.keyStates[Key]=false;
    for(int i=0;i<255;i++)
    {
        if(KeyPessUp.keyStates[i]==true)
        {
            check=1;
        }
    }
    if(KeyPessUp.acted==1&&check==0)
    {
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);
        KeyPessUp.acted=0;
    }


}
void KeyExit(unsigned char Key,int x,int y)
{
    if(Key==27)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
void MouseMove(int x,int y)
{
    int xpoint=x-KeyPessUp.lastx;
    int ypoint=y-KeyPessUp.lasty;
    KeyPessUp.lastx=x;
    KeyPessUp.lasty=y;
    KeyPessUp.yrot += xpoint*.3;
    KeyPessUp.xrot += ypoint*.3;
    if (KeyPessUp.xrot >=89) KeyPessUp.xrot = 89;
    if (KeyPessUp.xrot <= -89) KeyPessUp.xrot =-89;
    if (KeyPessUp.yrot >360) KeyPessUp.yrot -= 360;
    if (KeyPessUp.yrot < -360)KeyPessUp.yrot += 360;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    if(x>450 || x<350 ||y>350 || y<250)
    {
        glutWarpPointer(400,300);
        KeyPessUp.lastx=400;
        KeyPessUp.lasty=300;
    }
}
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE  | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);    
    glutCreateWindow("De Tai Nghien Cuu Khoa Hoc"); 
    glintIn();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);   
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutSpecialFunc(KeyPess);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(KeyUp);
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyExit);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(MouseMove);
    glutMotionFunc(MouseMove);
    glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);        
    glewInit();
    if(ENDABLE_FULL_SCREEN==TRUE)
    glutFullScreen();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `SIZE_KHUNG_CANH` and are there multiple coplanar triangles in the flickering zone?

Comment: all issues have been resolved I set value of glFrustum too small, I have increased 0.05f it works well.

Comment: Just wondering, what are your znear and zfar values? I might write up an answer about floats and depth buffers if that's the problem. Edit: Oh, I see @genpfault is asking the same question. So, what is your `SIZE_KHUNG_CANH` value?

Comment: giá trị znear = 0.01f and z = 140 * 3 I am big giá trị znear = 0.5f it is no longer bug im set value #define SIZE_KHUNG_CANH 140

Answer (score 0):

```
   float DefaultFus=0.001f;
   glFrustum (-DefaultFus, DefaultFus, -DefaultFus, DefaultFus, DefaultFus,SIZE_KHUNG_CANH*3 );
```

That's your problem right there: The near clipping place distance is very small compared to the scale to the scene. However the bigger the "scene scale"/"near clip" ratio is, the lower is the effective Z-buffer resolution.

Solution: Choose the near clip plane distance as large, i.e. far away as possible. Ideally you choose the value dynamically depending on the contents of the visible scene and the position of the view point.